# How to add Random Variables in general

Tags: probability, random-variables

I'm kind of confused how to add two arbitrary random variables. For example, suppose I have a binomial random variable $X$ with parameters $(n, p)$ and I have a Poisson Random Variable $Y$ with parameter $\lambda$. If I say, $Z = X + Y$ what would the pmf of $Z$ look like?

What about for two of the same random variables. For example, two degenerate random variables $X_1, X_2$ which have their distributions localized at $k_1$ and $k_2$ respectively.

I just don't really get how you can add these. I guess my main question is that they both have probabilities that sum to $1$, so how can you add them in any meaningful sense?

Answer (score 1):

Let it be that $X,Y$ are both random variables that only take values in $\mathbb Z$.

If $X$ and $Y$ are not defined on the same probability space then $X+Y$ makes no sense.

If $X$ and $Y$ are defined on the same probability space then for $k\in\mathbb Z$:

$$P(X+Y=k)=\sum_{i\in\mathbb Z}P(X=i,Y=k-i)$$

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent (hence are defined on the same probability space) then for $k\in\mathbb Z$:

$$P(X+Y=k)=\sum_{i\in\mathbb Z}P(X=i)P(Y=k-i)$$

---

If $P(X_i=k_i)=1$ for $i=1,2$ then it can be proved that $P(X_1=k_1,X_2=k_2)=1$ and consequently: $$P(X_1+X_2=k_1+k_2)=1$$again provided that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are defined on the same probability space.

Answer (score 0):

The probability mass function of a vector of random variables will equal the joint probability mass function of the random variables.

The joint probability mass function of *independent* random variables shall be the product of the probability mass functions of those random variables.

The probability mass functions of *identically distributed* random variables are identical, and these are a Poisson distributed random variables with parameter $\lambda$.

So....

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(\langle X_1,\ldots,X_n\rangle{=}\langle x_1,\ldots, x_n\rangle) ~&=~ \mathsf P\left(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^n( X_i{=}x_i)\right)\\&=~ \prod_{i=1}^n \mathsf P(X_i{=}x_i)\\[0ex]&~~\vdots\end{align}$$

Comment: That makes sense, thanks!

Comment: No problem! Glad to help.

Comment: I thought the OP is asking about **adding** two r.v.’s, in which case the resulting PDF would involve a convolution. Your answer seems to talk about joint PDFs.